# c++ function with variable number of arguments perform wrong 'string'-type convertion

Tags: c++

I ran into such a problem: i wrote some code and when i try to format some data (especially strings) i got strange result

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::endl
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void va_cout(string format, ...)
{
    vector<char> buf(256);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vsnprintf_s(&buf[0], buf.size(), buf.size() + strlen(format.c_str()), format.c_str(), args);
    va_end(args);
    cout << endl << "apply va_cout(""%s"", s) = " << &buf[0] << endl;
}

int main() {
    string s("myString");
    cout << endl << s << endl;
    va_cout("%s", s);
    va_cout("%s", s.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

// results

1. myString
2. apply va_cout(%s, s) = └¤#
3. apply va_cout(%s, s) = myString

why it returns line 2 ?

Answer (score 4):

`%s` can be used only with `char *` and `const char *`. You are passing a `std::string` and treating it like a `char *` in `vsnprintf_s()`. There is no implicit conversion from `std::string` to `char *`.  You need to call `std::string::c_str()` for that.

Comment: thank you. i'm trying to understand how to round out std::string::c_str()  using.